# multiple customTableViewCell using nib

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

i'm trying create multiple custom tableViewCells using Swift. i've used an objective-c project to convert into swift code, which probably is the reason why its not working. i've created 2 UITableViewCell subclasses with a xib. Then i added the subclasses to the xib class.

But when i register the nibs and try to show them in the tableView the tableView is empty. i've added connected the delegate to the uitableView

## viewDidLoad

```
    self.tableView?.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "TextViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TextViewCell")
    self.tableView?.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "AttachViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "AttachViewCell")
```

## cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
func tableView(tableView:UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    var cell: UITableViewCell? = nil


    if indexPath.row == 0 {


        var  textCell:TextViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TextViewCell") as? TextViewCell

        textCell.nameTextView.text = "Test"

        cell = TextViewCell()
    }

    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        var  attachCell:AttachViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AttachViewCell") as? AttachViewCell

        attachCell.attachLabel.text = "Attach image"


        cell = AttachViewCell()
    }




    return cell
}
```

Comment: What debugging have you tried? Are both attachCell and textCell non-nil? However, looking at the code, shouldn't you have `cell = textCell` and `cell = AttachViewCell` (no brackets) so that you return the dequeued cells?

Comment: You shouldn't create cells manually (`cell = TextViewCell`) but instead use the one that you dequeued and configured. In your code `cell` never has any text labels set, you should be returning `textCell`/`attachCell` instead of `cell`. Look at POB's answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using Xcode 6 beta 7, your `UITableViewController` class should look like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "TextViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TextViewCell")
        tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "AttachViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "AttachViewCell")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TextViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TextViewCell
            cell.nameTextView!.text = "Test" //@IBOutlet weak var nameTextView: UILabel!
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AttachViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as AttachViewCell
            cell.attachLabel!.text = "Attach image" //@IBOutlet weak var attachLabel: UILabel!
            return cell
        }
    }

}
```

Note that in Xcode 6 beta 7, `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` does not return a optional `UITableViewCell` anymore. So you have to use the previous code. If you use a previous version of Xcode 6 beta with `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` returning an Implicitly Unwrapped Optional `UITableViewCell`, you can write the following code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TextViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TextViewCell
        cell.nameTextView!.text = "Test" //@IBOutlet weak var nameTextView: UILabel!
        return cell
    }

    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AttachViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as AttachViewCell
        cell.attachLabel!.text = "Attach image" //@IBOutlet weak var attachLabel: UILabel!
        return cell
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: having issue :  NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'invalid nib registered for identifier (cell_printStatus) - nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UITableViewCell instance'